# Migration pre-import event/event-listener

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, migrate, event-listener

so i've got a custom Drupal 8 migration, where we're importing nodes from XML - everything's great. Now i want to add a pre-import function, so that before the migration. In Drupal 7 Migrate there was preImport() - what's the Drupal 8 method? I've found this article about [Events added to migration process](https://www.drupal.org/node/2544874), but it's still not clear to me how to proceed... thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own event subscriber, here a short guide: https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-register-event-subscriber-drupal8

Here a specific example of an EventSubscriber (my_migration/src/EventSubscriber/PreImportEvent.php):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_migration\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\migrate\Event\MigrateEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Class PreImportEvent
 *
 * @package Drupal\my_migration\EventSubscriber
 */
class PreImportEvent implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[MigrateEvents::PRE_IMPORT][] = [
      'preImport',
      0,
    ];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * @param $event
   */
  public function preImport($event) {
    // Do whatever you want with $event
  }

}
```

Now you need to register the service for your EventSubscriber (my_migration/my_migration.services.yml):

```
services:
  my_migration.subscriber.pre_import:
    class: Drupal\my_migration\EventSubscriber\PreImportEvent
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Note: If you need to alter your migration per field base you should better use a **process** plugin (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins).